# PHP - Make an associative array unique, key -> value and value -> key

Tags: php, unique, associative-array, key-value, array-flip

I have a little problem in php, which i find hard to explain in words. I have an associative array which contains key-value. I would like to make a function (or if there is already one) which would take an array as input and remove the duplicates but both ways.

For example:

In my array I have {a -> b} {a -> c} {b -> a} {b -> c} ...

From this view it does not seem like there is any duplicate, but to me {a -> b} and {b -> a} are duplicate. So I would like the function to see it as a duplicate and only return one of them.

I tried to use array_flip / array_unique to exchange the key and the values, in a loop but didn't quite work.

Could you help to find a way to do this even if it is array with a large length? or if there is a php function which does it.

Help would be really appreciated, thanks.

---

There is code to illustrate the idea:

For an array which would be like that:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b)
    [1] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => c )
    [2] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => a )
    [3] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => c )
)
```

Comment: Could you give a little more detailed code example?

Comment: So you only want to remove pairs that are identical, i.e. `a->b` & `b->a`, but not `a->b` & `a->c` or `a->b` & `c->b`?

Comment: *{a -> b} {a -> c}* do you have multiple keys with the same name (not possible)..? If I understood correctly if key *a* also exists as a value for example *b => a* it's a duplicate for you? If not then [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) is probably the function you're looking for..

Comment: exactly Alasdair, and Miloshio unfortunately i dont.

Comment: `[0] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b)` this is not an associative array, either your question is misleading or your example is wrong. I guess its the former, because you are talking about duplicate keys, which would not be possible.

Comment: the reason why it like that is because i want to be able to repeat the same key different times in the array. so to be able to have 'a' as key different times otherwise it wouldn't work I think because array keys are unique

Comment: or if you have a way of repeating the same key different time in the array, that would make it easier for me to also demonstrate

Answer (score 4):

This will remove your dublicates

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
     if (isset($array[$key])){
        if(isset($array[$value])){
            if($array[$value] == $key){
                unset($array[$value]);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: With the array `<?php $array = array(
 'a' => 'b',
 'b' => 'a',
 'c' => 'd',
 'd' => 'c'
); ?>` the array returns empty

Comment: It returns Array ( [a] => b [c] => d )

Comment: I didn't ask the question, @StringerB did, I encourage him to mark your answer as well

Comment: thanks for your replies, to be honest I don't understand your code!

Comment: $array is your array with dublicate values if you do the foreach it will remove all the dublicates exaple if your array is $array = array( 'a' => 'b', 'b' => 'a', 'c' => 'd', 'd' => 'c' ); the result is Array ( [a] => b [c] => d )

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
function cleanArray($array)
{
   $newArray = array();
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
      if (isset($array[$val]) && $array[$val] == $key) {
         if (!isset($newArray[$key]) && !isset($newArray[$val])) {
            $newArray[$key] = $val; 
         }      
         unset($array[$key], $array[$val]);
      }
   }    
   return array_merge($array, $newArray);
}
```

[Working example here](https://ignite.io/code/5128be14ec221e1307000000).